# Tensorflow GAN example unexpectedly quits

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running this Tensorflow example locally on Windows with an RTX 2060 and using the CuDNN framework:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/generative_examples/dcgan.ipynb

I am trying to run 1000 epochs, however, after exactly 370 epochs, the debugger quits "unexpectedly" (using Visual Studio 2019). I know this is both vague and hyper-specific, perhaps more appropriate for the GitHub page, but has anyone got any idea as to why this behaviour is occurring?

Comment: May be an issue from Visual Studio. Try using the Jupyter itself and run it.

Comment: Runs fine on jupyter.